# What, if any, ansi control sequences recolor already-printed text?

Tags: terminal, ansi-escape

Are there any ANSI control sequences which allow changing the color of existing text without knowing what it is? that is, what can I put in the second echo to affect the color of the printed text without knowing what was printed:

```
echo "$SOME_ARBITRARY_TEXT"
echo -en '<some series of ansi codes>'
```

I'm ideally hoping to find a way to set the background color of the full screen, but I'm interested in any control codes that allow changing colors without reprinting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't any: you can only write new text with new colors.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Thanks!